# vue button click handler firing when separate select input is changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I feel like I'm having the opposite problem that most people are having and it's making it hard to find a solution.

I have a vue component:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import {RouteIdentifier} from "@/domain/RouteIdentifier";
import {ref} from "vue";
import {getRouteDetails} from "@/api";

defineProps<{ routeIdentifiers: Array<RouteIdentifier> }>()
const selectedRoute = ref()
const loadedRouteName = ref()

async function loadRoute(routeId: number) {
    const details = await getRouteDetails(routeId)
    loadedRouteName.value = details.route.name
}

</script>

<template>
    <h1>Planned Routes</h1>
    <select v-model="selectedRoute">
        <option
                v-for="identifiers in routeIdentifiers"
                v-text="identifiers.routeName"
                :key="identifiers.id"
                :value="identifiers.id"
        >
        </option>
    </select>
    <div v-text="loadedRouteName"></div>
    <button :click="loadRoute(selectedRoute)">Load Route</button>
</template>
```

I'm rendering out a key value list of route ids and labels to populate a select element options (works fine).

[image: select input]
[image: select input selected]

The next plan was to put a "load route" button in that would use whatever route id is selected to make an API call to load the route details from the api.

This works, but the `loadRoute` function is firing when the select input's selection is changed and doesn't fire when the button is clicked.

[image: firing on select input change, not button click]

I'm not sure why this is happening. My click handler is specifically on the Load Route button and that button is not nested within the select element.

I know that I'm using the value from the model that the select element is using to store the selected value, but why would that trigger a method attached as a click event listener to a different element??

Comment: You are doing `<button :click="loadRoute(...)`, but it should be `<button @click="loadRoute(...)`

Comment: :facepalm: :facepalm: :facepalm: oh jeez, yeah you're right. I got so caught up in the action being weird that I missed that I was using the wrong syntax sugar :/ Thanks for point that out!

Comment: Just to bring more info on why it's happening: you're binding a function to a prop, which gets executed everytime the component is re-rendered. So apparently, everytime you select an item, it renders the component and triggers your `loadRoute` function from the template.